# Can you ask about configurations for musical equipment?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for a place to ask about the use of certain effects pedals with my bass guitar... is that considered off-topic here?

Comment: In general, as you will see from https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, questions on "usage of specific hardware" are fine. Was there a reason you were wondering about your particular question?

Comment: awesome thanks. I couldn't find that page for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Just to put it in a 'proper answer')

In general, as you will see from music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, questions on "usage of specific hardware" are fine.

Questions should still be specific, and not too opinion-based - in particular we don't like to get into "what's the best" of a particular type of equipment.